# d3dx12.h identifier undefined

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, directx-12

I'm learning DirectX 12. I want to use d3dx12.h header file but there are lots of error, most of them are "identifer 'something' undefined'.

So I searched about this problem and got some solutions.
This is "check Windows SDK version" and I updated VS2019. But that's not a good solution for me.

So I thought that DirectX 12 doesn't support GTX 750ti. I also found about it. But DX12 supports GTX 750ti.

I don't know why 'd3dx12.h' makes some errors.

I use:
Windows 10,
Visual studio 2019 (updated to latest version),
GTX 750ti,
d3dx12.h (latest version, https://github.com/microsoft/DirectX-Headers/blob/main/include/directx/d3dx12.h)

most of them are "identifier undefined". D3D12_BARRIER_SYNC, D3D12_BARRIER_ACCESS, D3D12_GLOBAL_BARRIER .... and D3D12_FEATURE_DATA_DISPLAYABLE, D3D12_FEATURE_DATA_D3D12_OPTIONS8, D3D12_FEATURE_DATA_D3D12_OPTIONS9, ..., D3D12_FEATURE_DATA_D3D12_OPTIONS12, and D3D12_WAVE_MMA_TIER_NOT_SUPPORTED, D3D12_TRI_STATE_UNKNOWN, D3D_SHADER_MODEL_6_7, etc. These are what is undefined. and there are even more things.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "D3D12_GLOBAL_BARRIER" is undefined  Engine  C:\Users\Beomseo Choi\source\repos\Game\Engine\d3dx12.h 4087
```

Comment: you need to show your code and what error you are getting

Comment: you have to install SDK as well as VS https://developer.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/windows-sdk/

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/directx/directx-12-ultimate-getting-started-guide/

Comment: Did you link d3d12.lib? Using a header alone doesnt make the program magically have the functionality it needs

Comment: please dont put errors messages in comments, paste them into the question. Did you follow that quickstart guide I pointed you at?

Comment: @Raildex Yes, I did

Comment: Those are not the error messages, they are your summary of them, just cut and paste the first few

Comment: @pm100 I decide that I will use the d3dx12,h in MS sample code. well,,, I know it's not a fundamental solution. I will test my code on other PC. Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'latest' version of D3DX12.H on the DirectX-Headers GitHub site is assuming you are using the Agility SDK 1.7 Preview which adds some new types like `D3D12_GLOBAL_BARRIER`.

You should use the D3DX12.H from the [release](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectX-Headers/releases/tag/v1.4.9) or perhaps [this copy](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates/blob/main/d3d12game_win32/d3dx12.h).

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't think of Agility SDK version.